# How can i take image upload value

Tags: asp.net

In my .aspx ,

```
<div id="pictureBox">
                            <img width="150" height="150" runat="server" id="imageField" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <input id="Upload" style="width: 200px; font-family: Myanmar3;" type="file" name="Upload"
                            runat="server" accept="image/*" >
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="upload_Click" CssClass="styleButton"
                            Text="Upload" />
```

In my .cs ,

```
  protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        if (Upload.Value !="")
        {
            System.IO.Stream fs = Upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
            img_uploadStream = Upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
            System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = CreateThumbnail(br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length),150);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            imageField.Src = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", "image/jpeg", base64String);

        }
    }
```

The image has upload and show successfully in "imageField" , but the value field of "Upload" input is empty when after "upload_Click" event . 
I want to take this value back to make another process !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The file is posted from the client to the server when the user picks it and click a button. Later it will be always empty unless the user selects it again.
You could save the file locally on the server if you need it again for further processing.

Comment: Can I use asp.net view state ?

Comment: Yes you can but the image would go from the client to the server for each request... not very performant....

Comment: How about using session , cookies ?

Comment: Session is Server side, it should be ok (unless you have many concurrent users). Cookies are client side so they have the same problems as viewstate. Furthermore they are limited to a few kB